# Is it possible for a geometry shader to do these things?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

Heres what I want to happen:

I want the GS to be able to decide whether to emit primitives to be rasterized and sent to fragment shader, or for the primitives to be emitted and looped back into the geometry shader, preferable in 1 draw call.

Is this possible? If not, what is the closest I can get to this?

Comment: "Looped back into the geometry shader?" Are you referring to transform feedback? You can effectively cause any primitive to be clipped and therefore not rasterized by setting the W component of all its vertices to **0**.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Is it possible for transform feedback to loop back into the geometry shader without having to put it in a  buffer first and use another draw call? Also, is it possible to choose whether to do this or to just rasterize the primitive within the shader? That's what im asking in this question.

Comment: In one draw call, I don't think so. But you can do what I mentioned in the first comment, and set the W coordinate to **0.0** for any primitive you don't want rasterized. Then you know when you get the transform feedback buffer, that any vertex with a **0.0** W coordinate is one that should be further processed. If you are really clever, then a feature in GL4 known as Geometry Shader instancing, which allows you to perform multiple invocations per-primitive, *may* help you. But I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, so that may not help at all.

Comment: Have you considered using tessellation shader?